# UI-State Calling other module controller

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I am using webpack for bundling, and i have 4 module in angularJS(lets assume Management,Student,Teacher and Admin) so i have few js files names common in both management and admin. i am using webpack to create a single "bundle.min.js" file.
Now suddenly i add a feature to admin and i reload the page and find the ui-state router calling management controller insted of calleing admin controller.

my admin config file:

```
...
.state('admin',{
url:'',
views:{
'main':{
templateUrl:'adminPage.html',
controller:'AdminPageCtrl',
controllerAs:'$admin'},
}
})
...
```

config of management module

```
   ...
    .state('management',{
    url:'',
    views:{
    'main':{
    templateUrl:'manPage.html',
    controller:'AdminPageCtrl',
    controllerAs:'$manage'},
    }
    })
    ...
```

admin index.js where i load all config and controllers:

```
 var angular = require('angular'),
        config = require('./config'),
        adminPageCtrl= require('./controller/AdminPageCtrl');

module.exports = angular
    .module('myApp.admin',[])
    .controller('AdminPageCtrl', adminPageCtrl)
```

management index.js i load all config and controllers:

```
    var angular = require('angular'),
        config = require('./config'),
        adminPageCtrl= require('./controller/AdminPageCtrl');

module.exports = angular
    .module('myApp.management',[])
    .controller('AdminPageCtrl', adminPageCtrl)
```

app.js where i load all modules

```
var angular = require('angular'),
    adminModule = require('./admin/index'),
    managementModule = require('./management/index'),

angular.module('myApp',['myApp.admin','myApp.management'])
```

The above is calling  AdminPageCtrl of management module, instead of AdminPageCtrl  of admin module.

Comment: Could you please add the config of the management module, in order to see the differences between them.

Comment: @ManuelObregozo I have added Config and all other related..

Comment: Your issue could be related to the URLs. You have two base states with same URL, try to specify a different URL for both of them.

Comment: @ManuelObregozo I am having both in different folders, i.e manager in manager folder and admin in admin folder...but manager and admin folder have same sub-folders names that is controller and in that controller folder. those are the folder where i am adding all controllers file.